# How to support bigint in datetime

Tags: t-sql

The result of `datediff(ss, '01/01/1970', '12/31/2050')` is a `bigint` so `datediff` is overflowing.

How can I get from a `bigint` value to its equivalent date and back again if the max a date can be in SQL is `int`?

I need to be able to store number of seconds between `01/01/1970` and `12/31/2050` in SQL (which I do as a `char`) but convert that value to its calendar date for display in a web page.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: All linux/unixes have this problem as well. It is well known that the [epoch will overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Representing_the_number) if not changed from 32bits.

Answer (score 4):

This will give you miliseconds. Easy to adapt to seconds...

```
declare @dfrom datetime = '1970-01-01 16:15:33.021'
declare @dto datetime = '2058-01-01 15:00:55.557'

declare @diff bigint = 
    cast(DATEDIFF(d, @dfrom, @dto) as bigint) * 24 * 3600 * 1000 
     + DATEDIFF(ms, cast(@dfrom as time), cast(@dto as time))    

declare @dreverse datetime = 
    dateadd(ms, @diff % (1000 * 3600 * 24), 
        dateadd(day, @diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24), @dfrom))   

select @dfrom as [From], @dto as [To], @diff as [Diff], @dreverse as [Reverse] for xml path('')
```

gives:

```
<From>1970-01-01T16:15:33.020</From>
<To>2058-01-01T15:00:55.557</To>
<Diff>2777064322537</Diff>
<Reverse>2058-01-01T15:00:55.557</Reverse>
```

Comment: This is not a good idea, unless you are happy to ignore the hours and seconds on the first and last day. Datediff counts "boundaries". IF you do select datediff(d,'2013-01-01 04:00:00','2013-01-02 10:00:00') then result is 1 (day), not 1.25 days, because the return type is integer.

Comment: Davos, that is exactly why there's the ms part on second line... ?

Comment: Hmm I missed that, but there's still an issue if after you cast as time that your From time could be later in the day that your TO time, so you would add negative milliseconds. Maybe subtract from a full day's milliseconds if it's negative

Comment: Any tests to prove your claim Davos?

Comment: declare $dfrom datetime = '2014-01-01 16:15:33.021'
declare $dto datetime = '2014-01-02 15:00:55.557'

select DATEDIFF(ms, cast($dfrom as time), cast($dto as time))

This gives a negative number (Please change $ to the "at" symbol. Can't use it in comments)

Comment: Thanks Davos, the statement must be run in full. Not just the first part or the last part, but both of them. Please draw the intervals on a piece of paper. You'll understand that the negative result of the time part is correctly adjusting the date part.

Comment: As a note, this doesn't work on SQL server 2005 because the datediff using d doesn't handle years and because cast time doesn't exist.  Just an FYI for others.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast datetimes as floats where they will denote the number of days since 1900-01-01 00:00:00. The parts less than days are then simply the fractions. Substracting these numbers and scaling by seconds in a day should do.

DECLARE @d1 DATETIME

DECLARE @d2 DATETIME

SELECT @d1 = '01/01/1970'

SELECT @d2 = '12/31/2050'

SELECT (CAST (@d2 AS FLOAT) - CAST(@d1 AS FLOAT)) * 3600 * 24

But you'll probably be able to find nicer solutions ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SecondsSince1970(@date datetime)
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        CASE WHEN @date > '2038-01-19'
            THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(ss, '2038-01-19', @date) AS bigint)
                + DATEDIFF(ss, '1970-01-01', '2038-01-19')
            ELSE DATEDIFF(ss, '1970-01-01', @date)
        END
END
```